# Target number is the sum of Consecutive Squares

Tags: java

I am trying to write a java code for a program that outputs all possible sets of consecutive squares that add to target number. for example if I input 5 I would get [1,2] since 1^2+2^2=5, or if I input 29 I would get [2,3,4]. If I input 25 however, I would get both [5] and [3,4].

So far I have

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
        int t = 25;//147439;

        findConsecutiveNumbersWithSumOfSquares(t);

        scanner.close();
    }

    private static void findConsecutiveNumbersWithSumOfSquares(int t) {
        for (int start = 1; start < t; start++) {
            int currentSum = start * start;
            int end = start + 1;

            while (currentSum < t) {
                currentSum += end * end;
                end++;
            }

            if (currentSum == t) {
                printConsecutiveNumbers(start, end - 1);
            }
        }
    }

    private static void printConsecutiveNumbers(int start, int end) {
        for (int i = start; i <= end; i++) {
            System.out.print(i + " ");
        }
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

Basically what this does is it goes through all possible numbers less than target number t and sees if consecutive sums add up to the target number and then adds one more number to the sequence once that consecutive sum exceeds t. This code however is inefficient for large numbers and I don't know if there is a less complex way to do this. For example if I wanted to find a number with 4 instances of consecutive squares summing to a target number it would take too long.

Comment: One potential save is you only have to go through `start <= sqrt(t)` since any number above that will always be bigger than t (`sqrt(t)^2 = t, => sqrt(t) + n > t where n is any integer that is non 0`)

Comment: This does reduce time but not significantly enough for large numbers like the one I put in the comment next to t.

Comment: I was able to get the program to run with a large number, and rather quickly. Try this number: 5177125

Comment: I've seen this problem recently, but failed to find it. There is a similar LeetCode problem:  https://leetcode.com/problems/consecutive-numbers-sum/ This LeetCode returns a single `int`, which is the number of solutions. Another version returns either a `List<List<Integer>>` or an `int[][]`, which returns the solutions that were found.